# Redis Lua function call failing with CROSSSLOT error

Tags: redis, lua, redis-cluster

I have a Redis 7.x cluster with 3 master nodes running on ports 7000, 7001, 7002. Each master has 1 slave/replica.

I am trying to load and run this Lua based function:

```
#!lua name=paramsLogLib
local function paramsLog(keys, args)
    local param1 = keys[1]
    local param2 = keys[2]
    local param3 = keys[3]
    redis.log(redis.LOG_NOTICE, param1, param2, param3)
end
redis.register_function('paramsLog', paramsLog)
```

The function has been loaded in all the 3 master nodes.

I tried to call the function **paramsLog** from all the 3 master nodes:

`127.0.0.1:7000> fcall paramsLog 3 p1 p2 p3`

`127.0.0.1:7001> fcall paramsLog 3 p1 p2 p3`

`127.0.0.1:7002> fcall paramsLog 3 p1 p2 p3`

I get the same error:

`(error) CROSSSLOT Keys in request don't hash to the same slot`

How can I pass different parameters to any function in the Redis? Why does Redis need to check the hash slot of the parameters itself?

Comment: Are these parameters keys or not? If so, they all have to reside on the same server. If not, you should pass `0` instead of `3`, since that argument indicates the number of keys.

Comment: okay, got it. @for_stack has suggested to use args.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the Redis Cluster command, including Lua script, runs on a single node, and it cannot access keys on other nodes in the cluster. If your command/script needs to access multiple keys, which are not located on the same slot, you get the *CROSSSLOT* error.

In your case, your 3 keys, i.e. p1, p2, p3, located on different slots (maybe also on different nodes), and that's why you get the error.

As @Kevin mentioned in the comment, if p1, p2 and p3 are not keys, but parameters, you can pass them as arguments, and access them with `args`. If they indeed the keys, you can try to use [hash-tag](https://redis.io/docs/reference/cluster-spec/) to ensure these keys located on the same slot. So that your script can access all of them.